# Is there a way to reference an object's base __class__ from class scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, superclass

I have a series of classes all, inheriting from one of several possible parents which all share a base class. Each class has a class-scope Dict[str, object] `parameters` which is based on the base class `parameters`

```
from copy import deepcopy


class BaseClass:
    parameters = {
        'example_param1': ParamObject(name='example_param1', editable=True),
    }


class MiddleClass(Baseclass):
    parameters = {
        **deepcopy(Baseclass.parameters),
        'example_param2': ParamObject(name='example_param2', editable=False),
    }


class ChildClass(MiddleClass):
    parameters = {
        **deepcopy(MiddleClass.parameters),
        'example_param3': ParamObject(name='example_param3', editable=True),
    }
```

This implementation does the job, but I find the `**deepcopy(Baseclass.parameters),` line unsatisfying. These child classes are going to be edited over time by someone with only a basic understanding of coding so I want to make the code as simple and cut-and-pasteable as possible.

Is there anything I can call at class scope to get the equivilant of `super().__class__`? I want the user to be able to change the base class from, say, `MiddleClass` to `MiddleClass2` without needing to remember to change the base class in multiple locations.

Comment: Note that `super().__class__` wouldn't do what you want either, even inside an instance method - it just gives `super`.

Comment: This is probably a case for `__init_subclass__`, though it's not clear to me how best to structure this.

Comment: Do the parameters absolutely have to be in a dict?  If they were directly attributes of the class, you'd get the desired inheritance behavior for free.  If they had to be distinguishable from other class attributes, a naming convention (such as `*_param*` in your example) might suffice.

Comment: I would use metaclasses for this. You could walk the MRO and combine all these parameters.

Comment: @alkasm `__init_subclass__` exists to avoid having to use a metaclass for this type of use case.

Comment: Sure, I was just stating another approach which had not been suggested yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a metaclass. Check all of the classes in the inheritance tree to see if they have the `parameter`s field. If they do, then merge them together and set the property on the class instance.

```
class ParamMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        class_types = [cls] + list(bases)
        parameters = {}
        for class_type in class_types:
            if hasattr(class_type, "parameters"):
                parameters.update(class_type.parameters)
        cls.parameters = parameters
        super().__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

Example:

```
class Foo(metaclass=ParamMeta):
    parameters = {"a": "b"}


class Bar(Foo):
    pass


class Fizz(Bar):
    parameters = {"c": "d"}


print(Foo.parameters)
print(Bar.parameters)
print(Fizz.parameters)
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 'b'}
{'a': 'b'}
{'c': 'd', 'a': 'b'}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `__init_subclass__` to add parameters from parent classes directly to the explicitly defined `parameters` attribute, at the cost of the insertion order being reversed (should that matter).

```
class ParameterBase:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for pc in cls.__bases__:
            d = getattr(pc, 'parameters', {})
            cls.parameters.update(d)

class BaseClass(ParameterBase):
    parameters = {
        'example_param1': ParamObject(name='example_param1', editable=True),
    }


class MiddleClass(BaseClass):
    parameters = {
        'example_param2': ParamObject(name='example_param2', editable=False),
    }


class ChildClass(MiddleClass):
    parameters = {
        'example_param3': ParamObject(name='example_param3', editable=True),
    }
```

Comment: In this case the order, while not a big deal, would cause some unintuitive side effects elsewhere. I will mention though that I didn't know __init_subclass__ existed and I'm already thinking of other places where it can help me out, so thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your class inherits from only one class, you can use a metaclass:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, namespace):
        namespace['parameters'] = {
            **deepcopy(parents[0].parameters),
            **namespace['parameters']
        }

        return super().__new__(cls, name, parents, namespace)

class MiddleClass(Baseclass, metaclass=Meta):
    parameters = {
        'example_param2': ParamObject(name='example_param2', editable=False),
    }
```

This is of course a simplified version that doesn't handle multiple parent classes, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metaclasses, such as the other answers suggested, but I'm not sure how easier that would be for a new programmer to understand.

You can access the classes a class inherithed from by calling `__bases__` on the class. Sadly though, on python you cannot reference the class you're creating on the class body, meaning you can't do:

```py
class A:
   bases = A.__bases__  # Invalid code, A is not defined yet
```

If you want to do this, while mantaining parameters static, you can do this after the class definition, and it will have the exact behaviour you're looking for, although a bit ugly:

```py
class BaseClass:
    parameters = {
        'example_param1': ParamObject(name='example_param1', editable=True),
    }


class MiddleClass(Baseclass):
    pass

MidleClass.parameters = {
    **deepcopy(MidleClass.__bases__[0].parameters),
    'example_param2': ParamObject(name='example_param2', editable=False),
}
```

Now, to improve things a bit, if your `parameters` is really always a 'Dict[str, object]', you don't need to do a deepcopy, since using the `**` acts in a functional way. You can also handle multiple parent classes using the `__bases__` value, to ensure every value is being captured. So, if I were to do this, I would do something like this:

```py
def base_parameters(cls):
    parameters = {}
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        parameters.update(base.parameters)

    return parameters


class BaseClass:
    parameters = {
        'example_param1': ParamObject(name='example_param1', editable=True),
    }


class MiddleClass(BaseClass):
    pass

MiddleClass.parameters = {
    **base_parameters(MiddleClass),
    'example_param2': ParamObject(name='example_param2', editable=False),
}


class ChildClass(MiddleClass):
    pass

ChildClass.parameters = {
    **base_parameters(ChildClass),
    'example_param3': ParamObject(name='example_param3', editable=True),
}
```